# How to check if a batch of specified keys exist in a given S3 bucket using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using SDK 1.x, and `doesObjectExist` works well for one single object.
But it has a bad performance when many objects need to be checked.

Is there any bulk API to check object exists or not in S3?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions would be to request all objects in a bucket by `listObjectsV2`  and then compare it with the given list locally